# Create a zip file and send to client without saving it on server

Tags: java, spring, zip

I have a Java server application (Java + Spring). Actually, when required this application (1) creates a zip file by collecting files from a directory, (2) saves this file on the hard disk, and (3) sends the result file to the client who required that.

Question: How could I skip the saving step (2), and send directly the zipFile without saving it on the hard disk?

In this way I will save some resources and I also don't need to "clean" the hard disk.

Thank you

NOTES:
The creation of the ZIP file is as following:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/requireZip")
    public ResponseEntity zipRequired() {
    //SOMETHING BEFORE

        if( aConditionIsFalse ) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        } //else create and return a zip file

        String theFolder = "/my/path/";
        String resultFile = theFolder+"FILES-list.zip";   //the container-zip file
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            for (FileData aFile : fileList) {  //  collect the files to the result zip file
                File fileToZip = new File(theFolder + aFile.getName());

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName()));

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
                fis.close();
            }
            zipOut.close();
            fos.close();
        }
         catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // Read the file just saved on the disk, then return it
        FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(resultFile);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(file);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of a `FileOutputStream`, you should be able to use an output stream directly to the recipient (or a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to hold it in memory first, but I wouldn't recommend that). For example, using a `StreamingResponseBody`

Comment: thanks for your answer: why you don't recommend that?

Comment: It wasn't an answer, but a comment hinting at a solution direction. Any case, I don't recommend using `ByteArrayOutputStream`, because if your zipfile is very large, it can consume a lot of memory (more than twice the actual file size, because when you obtain the data from it, it copies it. In addition, for extremely large zipfiles (> 2GiB), it wouldn't even work because of maximum array sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the response stream in `ZipOutputStream` and write directly to it. Just add `HttpServletResponse` as method parameter and spring will provide you with it.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/requireZip")
public void zipRequired(HttpServletResponse response) {
  if (some condition) {
    response.setStatus(204);
    return;
  }
  String theFolder = "/my/path/";
  String resultFile = theFolder+"FILES-list.zip";   //the container-zip file
  //set name of the download file
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + resultFile);
  try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());) {
    for (FileData aFile : fileList) {  //  collect the files to the result zip file
      File fileToZip = new File(theFolder + aFile.getName());
      zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName()));
      Files.copy(fileToZip.toPath(), zipOut);//easier copying, assuming java 7+
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Under certain conditions, I should not return any file, but `ResponseEntity.noContent();` . Where could I set that different response value?

Comment: @fresko If those conditions are met, you can set the status in the response - `response.setStatus(204);` and then don't write to the output stream.

Comment: Chaosfire: everything seems OK (but I still have to test that). Last question, the zip file that will be returned does not have a name set. `String resultFile` is not used and I cannot access to a set method for the name

Comment: @fresko You need to set the content disposition header - `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=".concat(resultFile));`